# HTML - Fancybox - Adding text below image thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am using an HTML code for simple image gallery on my website from this demo: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ Is there an easy way to add text below each thumbnail which would be different from the image title (which is displaying after clicking on a thumbnail)?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Thanks for your help, but it was't quite what I asked. Anyway, my friend has solved it. Both image link and description must be included next to each other in one parent element, like this:

```
<div>
    <a ... ><img src="image link" alt="First picture" /></a>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Then the width of the div is set to the width of the image thumbnail, causing the description to "drop" down below the thumbnail.

Comment: The code for single image looks like this: <a class="fancybox" href="1_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a> . I tried to add <p> or <span> tags afterwards and position them below using CSS, but it corrupted the gallery structure - each thumbnail started to appear on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try using **inline** option? As it is quite similar to what you want.

**Link Button**

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline</a>
```

**Inline Html**

```
<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
  <p>Your Main image could be here</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: almost fine - just leave this #inline1 div visible and wrap it in hidden div ...now it works

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text inside the `<p>` tag and add some CSS to fix the layout

```
<a class="fancybox" href="1_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
    <img src="1_s.jpg" alt="">
    <p>some text</p>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.fancybox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fancybox img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way the text works as a link to the image. I want it to be either a simple description or a link somewhere else.